# How to Mock Mongo Cursor object with Node.js and Sinon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sinon

I need to add unit-test coverage to some old code, and having difficulty creating a mock [Cursor object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html) which will allow chaining of project, limit, skip, toArray as seen below.

```
collection.find({}, (err, res) => {
......
    const results = res.project(projection)
                       .limit(limitCount)
                       .skip(skipCount)
                       .toArray()
```

I have mocked DB/collection/find before with the toArray available on the response object, (something like below), but not sure how to handle the chaining of the other cursor 'values' mentioned above.

```
            let fakeFind = () => {
                return {
                    toArray: () => {
                        return Promise.resolve(testCustomerRecord);
                    }
                };
            }

            let stubFind = sinon.stub().callsFake(fakeFind);
            
            let mockDb = {
                collection: () => {
                    return {
                        find: stubFind
                    };
                }
            };
```

I tried adding them as properties, functions, but get back error like this:

TypeError: item.project(...).limit is not a function

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stub.returnsThis();` method allows you to stub chain method calls.

E.g.

```
import sinon from 'sinon';

// service under test
const service = {
  find(db) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      db.collection.find({}, (err, res) => {
        const results = res.project({ a: 1 }).limit(10).skip(0).toArray();
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  },
};

describe('68483854', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mockRes = {
      project: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      limit: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      skip: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      toArray: sinon.stub().returns('mock data'),
    };
    const mockDb = {
      collection: {
        find: sinon.stub().callsFake((where, callback) => {
          callback(null, mockRes);
        }),
      },
    };
    const actual = await service.find(mockDb);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'mock data');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mockRes.project, { a: 1 });
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mockRes.limit, 10);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mockRes.skip, 0);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mockRes.toArray);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, surprised I didn't come across before in my searching!

Comment: How to do this if the find is returning a cursor

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala Please ask a new question, this test strategy stub too many methods, and test implementations. I will not recommend this way anymore, instead, I will start a memory MongoDB server and seed the data. Just need to assert and output data is correct or not.